# Problem with python and __import__

Tags: python, import

Sorry for the generic title, will change it once I understand the source of my problem
I have the following structure:

```
foo/
foo/__init__.py
foo/bar/
foo/bar/__init__.py
foo/bar/some_module.py
```

When I try to import some_module by doing so:

```
from foo.bar import some_module
```

it works like a charm.
But this is no good for me, since I only know the name of the module to import in runtime. so if I try:

```
from foo.bar import *
mod=__import__('some_module')
```

I get an error. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this? and why is this happening?

Why is that? I am not quite sure I completely understand the concept behind python packages. I thought they were equivalent to java's packages and thus

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: your `some_module` is already imported!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the proper way to do this is:

```
mod = __import__('foo.bar', fromlist = ['some_module'])
```

This way even the 'foo.bar' part can be changed at runtime. 
As a result `some_module`will be available as `mod.some_module`; use getattr if you want it in a separate variable:

```
the_module = getattr(mod, 'some_module')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from foo.bar import *
```

is a bad practice since it imports `some_module` into the global scope.

You should be able to access your module through:

```
import foo.bar
mod = getattr(foo.bar, 'some_module')
```

It can be easily demonstrated that this approach works:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> getattr(os.path, 'basename')
<function basename at 0x00BBA468>
>>> getattr(os.path, 'basename\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    getattr(os.path, 'basename\n')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'basename
'
```

P.S. If you're still interested in using your kind of import statement. You need an `eval`:

```
from foo.bar import *
eval('some_module')
```

To clarify: not only it's bad practice to use `*`-import it's even **worse** in combination with `eval`. So just use `getattr`, it's designed exactly for situations like yours.

Comment: -1 for recommending eval().  Always use globals()['some_module'] instead if all you want is to look up the value from global scope.

Comment: All right, +1 again for your clarification.  getattr() is the right answer here.  If you need to use __import__(), see kurczak's answer.

Comment: Uh oh, now I get "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited".  My apologies -- I saw eval() in a code block and automatically clicked -1.

Comment: sorry, this doesn't seem to work... doing this raise an error:
'module' object has no attribute 'some_module' 
(Dunno why it refers to foo.bar as a module...)

Comment: It works perfectly, it just means that `foo.bar` doesn't have attribute `some_module`. Where are you getting the name from?

Comment: it works perfectly, if you add the line with getattr that's mentioned in kurczac's answer

Comment: and you somehow missing the same line in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__):

> Direct use of `__import__()` is rare, except in cases where you want to import a module whose name is only known at runtime.

However, the dotted notation should work:

```
mod = __import__('foo.bar.some_module')
```