# Problem with import in Python

Tags: python, import

[Closing NOTE]
Thank you everyone that trying to help me.

I've found the problem and it have nothing to do with python understanding of mine (which is little). :p

The problem is that I edit the wrong branch of the same project, Main.py in one branch and XWinInfos.py in another branch.

Thanks anyway.

[Original Question]
I am a Java/PHP/Delphi programmer and only use Python when hack someone else program -- never to write a complex Python myself. Since I have a short free time this week, I determine to write something non-trivia with Python and here is my problem

First I have python files like this:

```
src/
    main.py
    SomeUtils.py
```

In "SomeUtils.py, I have a few functions and one class:

```
...
def funct1 ...

def funct2 ...

class MyClass1:
    __init__(self):
        self. ....
...
```

Then in "main.py", I use the function and class:

```
from SomeUtils import *;

def main():
    funct1();               # Use funct1   without problem;
    aMyObj1 = MyClass1();   # Use MyClass1 with error

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main();
```

The problem is that the functions are used without any problem what so ever but I cannot use the class.

The error is:

```
NameError: global name 'MyClass1' is not defined
```

What is the problem here? and What can I do?

EDIT: Thanks for answers for I still have problem. :(
When I change the import statements to:

```
from SomeUtils import funct1
from SomeUtils import MyClass1
```

I have this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name MyClass1
```

**EDIT 2:----------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks you guys.

I think, it may be better to post the actual code, so here it is:

NOTE: I am aware about ";" and "(...)" but I like it this way.

Here is the dir structure.
[DIRS http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1961549/images/Python_import_prolem_dir_.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1961549/images/Python_import_prolem_dir_.png)
as you see, I just add an empty **init**.py but it seems to make no different.

Here is main.py:

```
from XWinInfos import GetCurrentWindowTitle;
from XWinInfos import XWinInfo;

def main():
    print GetCurrentWindowTitle();
    aXWinInfo = XWinInfo();

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main();
```

Here is XWinInfos.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen;
from subprocess import PIPE;
from RegExUtils import GetTail_ofLine_withPrefix;

def GetCurrentWindowID():
    aXProp = Popen(["xprop", "-root"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0];
    aLine  = GetTail_ofLine_withPrefix("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\): window id # 0x", aXProp);
    return aLine;

def GetCurrentWindowTitle():
    aWinID    = GetCurrentWindowID(); 
    aWinTitle = GetWindowTitle(aWinID);
    return aWinTitle;

def GetWindowTitle(pWinID):
    if (aWinID == None): return None

    aWMCtrlList = Popen(["wmctrl", "-l"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]; 
    aWinTitle   = GetTail_ofLine_withPrefix("0x[0-9a-fA-F]*" + aWinID + "[ ]+[\-]?[0-9]+[ ]+[^\ ]+[ ]+", aWMCtrlList);
    return aWinTitle;

class XWinInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        aWinID = GetCurrentWindowID();
        self.WinID = pWinID;
        self.Title = GetWindowTitle(pWinID);
```

The file RegExUtils.py holds a function "GetTail_ofLine_withPrefix" which work fine so.

If I use "from XWinInfos import *;", the error goes "NameError: global name 'XWinInfo' is not defined".

If I use "from XWinInfos import XWinInfo;", the error goes "ImportError: cannot import name XWinInfo".

Please helps.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should that line read "from SomeUtils import *" ?

Comment: Could you post actual code here? What's "from XWinInfos import *"? Shouldn't it be "SomeUtils"? What's your Python-Path like? Is there a "__init__.py" in "src/"? And: Python does not need those fancy ";" at the end of each line. You should drop them...

Comment: Yes It should be "SomeUtils" and no, there is no __init__.py. Should I create it? and what should be inside of it?

Comment: It can be also empty but it must exist

Comment: I've post the actual code, please have a look ("EDIT 2").

Comment: are you sure this is the actual code? in the class you define aWinID, but then use pWinID (with a 'p' instead of an 'a'), so you'd get a NameError

Comment: problem was exactly what I told you, it would.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... there's several typos in your example, so I wonder if your actual code has some typos as well.  Here's the complete source from a quick test that does work fine without import errors.

SomeUtils.py:

```
def funct1():
    print('Function 1')

def funct2():
    print('Function 2')

class MyClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyClass')
```

main.py:

```
from SomeUtils import *

def main():
    funct1()
    aObj = MyClass1()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

[EDIT Based on OP additional info]

I still can't recreate the same error, but the code you posted won't initially work for at least a couple of errors in the XWinInfox.py **init** method:

```
self.WinID = pWinID #change to 'aWinID' since pWinID is not defined
self.Title = GetWindowTitle(pWinID)  #change to 'aWinID'since pWinID is not defined
```

so a corrected version would read:

```
self.WinID = aWinID
self.Title = GetWindowTitle(aWinID)
```

Also, you have a typo in your init file name, there should be two underscores before AND after the 'init' word.  Right now you have `'__init_.py'` and it should be `'__init__.py'`, however this shouldn't keep your code from working.

Because I don't have the RegExUtils.py code, I just stubbed out the methods that rely on that file.  With the stubbed methods and correcting the aforementioned typos, the code you post now works.

Answer (score 2):

why are you importing from `XWinInfos`? you should be importing from `SomeUtils`. Not to mention that `*`-style imports are discouraged.

**Edit**: your error

> ImportError: cannot import name MyClass1

basically tells you that there is no `MyClass1` defined in the `SomeUtils`. It could be because you have another `SomeUtils.py` file somewhere on the system path and it being imported instead. If that file doesn't have `MyClass1`, you'd get this error.

**Again:** it's irrelevant whether you class `MyClass1` exist. What might be the case is that you have another `XWinInfos.p(y|o|w)` somewhere on your system and it's being imported. Otherwise: **norepro**.

Comment: Thanks for posting. XWinInfos is a typing mistake so it is supposed to be SomeUtils. Still the problem persist with the same error message.

Comment: After your edit: Thanks again. I am sure that MyClass1 exist (copy-paste). And if it import another module, how can funct1 work.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to rewrite main.py as follows:

```
import SomeUtils as util

def main():
    util.funct1()               # Use funct1   without problem;
    aMyObj1 = util.MyClass1()   # Use MyClass1 with error

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A few quick notes:

- There is no need for semicolons in
  Python unless you have more than one
  statement on a line
- There is no need
  to wrap conditional tests in
  parentheses except for grouping
- `from
  module import *` is discouraged as it
  pollutes the global namespace

Comment: Sorry about the typing mistake, I change the name so that it would distract the actual problem (but it seems to be a mistake here). Anyway, When I change the import section to: "from SomeUtils import funct1" and "from SomeUtils import MyClass1". I have this error "ImportError: cannot import name MyClass1".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean

```
from SomeUtils import *
```

however, that does not trigger the error for me. This works fine for me:

SomeUtils.py

```
def funct1():
    print 4

class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self):
        print 8
```

main.py

```
from SomeUtils import *

def main():
    funct1()               # Use funct1   without problem;
    aMyObj1 = MyClass1()   # Use MyClass1 without error

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Comment: You are right about my mis-type, but I did have problem with the Class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is naturally linked to a lot of SO older one.
See, just for reference, [SO1342128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342128/problem-with-python-and-import) and [SO1057843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057843/python-import-problem)

Comment: completely and utterly irrelevant to this question