# Python module with a dash, or hyphen (-) in its name

Tags: python, module, import

I have an existing python module with a dash in its name, foo-bar.py

Changing the module name is something I would prefer to avoid as the module is shared, and I would have to chase down all the places it is used so that my special case will work.

Is there a way to load a module whose name contains the typically forbidden '-'?

(I do understand that this isn't a best practice. But for this situation I would prefer not to redesign and test a much larger set of applications.  Also I don't think my corporate masters would approve of my taking the time to implement such a change.)

Comment: This answer in particular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them/762693#762693

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to use dashes in Python files when trying to import them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761519/is-it-ok-to-use-dashes-in-python-files-when-trying-to-import-them)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can do that using [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__). For example:

```
foobar = __import__("foo-bar")
```

But you really should rename the module instead. That way you can avoid confusion where the filename of the module is different from the identifier used in the program.

Comment: Thanks.  I do understand that conventions should be followed wherever practical.  I will be bringing up this specific issue during a departmental code review.

Answer (score 86):

I know this question has already been answered to satisfaction of the asker, but here is another answer which I believes has some merit above using `__import__()`.

```
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module("path.to.my-module")
# mod.yourmethod()
```

According to the docs:

```
"This provides an implementation of import which is portable to any 
Python interpreter. This also provides an implementation which is 
easier to comprehend than one implemented in a programming language 
other than Python."
```

`Python 2.7` + only

Comment: I was searching for how to do this and your answer applies better to my situation than the older answer. It's always good if you see a distinct answer to the already existing one to add it as a new answer so that people in a position like myself can find all the relevant information in one place.

Comment: in the python documentation, `__import__` is discouraged (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__)) in the favor of `importlib`. it could cause a lot of issues. (see also [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342128/problem-with-python-and-import))