# Call webservice method that contains hyphen

Tags: python, zeep

I am trying to call SAP web service using zeep module. We have a web service method called “*-CTSH*-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD”  and when try to call that method, getting the error 
” Service has no operation '_' “ . Since method name has hyphen, python is not considering the strings after hyphen.

```
message = client.service_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD()
```

Note: We cannot change the SAP web service method name as SAP team is following the certain naming convention for method name.

Comment: if this is an external python module, how exactly did it manage to define a method with a hyphen without getting an error?

Comment: You should maybe show the declaration of such object. Are you sure it is written in Python?

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid python syntax. Python is parsing the code as:

```
client.service_ - CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD()
```

I.e. subtraction of `client.service_` and that function call.

You can try to use `getattr` instead:

```
method = getattr(client, "service_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD")
method()   # call the method
```

Assuming that `zeep` does not "normalize" the invalid method name in some other way.

---

Working example:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> setattr(A, "service_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD", lambda self: print('called'))
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> getattr(a, "service_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD")()
called
>>> method = getattr(a, "service_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD")
>>> method
<bound method <lambda> of <__main__.A object at 0x7f4651c5e518>>
>>> method()
called
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
import client.service

method_called =  __import__("_-CTSH_-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD")
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name/24659400)

Comment: method_called = __import__("-CTSH-HC_RFC_XCHG_RATE_UPLOAD")