# Django App installed from Git but not found

Tags: django, git, pip, django-apps

I want to install some apps I have developed and are hosted on my own git service but since it appears they have been correctly installed, when I add them to `INSTALLED_APPS` throws me a `ModuleNotFoundError`

This is my setup file for the app

```
setup(
    name='my-teams',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    license='GPL',
    description='Teams app',
    long_description=README,
    url='https://<url>/my-teams',
    author='...',
    author_email='...',
    classifiers=[
        ...
    ],
    install_requires=[requirements],
)
```

This is my `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_teams',
]
```

And this is what I've added to my requirements.txt file:

```
-e git+https://<url>/my-teams.git@master#egg=my_teams
```

When I install requirements.txt it seems to be okay:

```
Found existing installation: my-teams 0.1
    Uninstalling my-teams-0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled my-teams-0.1
```

And it appears when I execute `pip freeze`

```
-e git+https://<url>/my-teams.git@cfa8cbf84d8d91ce573f33da3156e8f7f241d63a#egg=my_teams
```

Finally, when I run `python manage.py runserver` it throws me the exception:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_teams'
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have `my_teams` python module in your git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the name in the setup as 'my-teams', please change it into 'my-teams' in installed apps in settings.py

Comment: modules with "-" work in Python? I don't think so (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name)