# Django - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import a python file from another python file in Django. There is a function I want to call from the other file, but every time I import the file I get an error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ams/faces-train.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ams.conn import conn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ams'
```

What the problem is? I have tried everything but I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: have you added `ams` to your `installed_apps`

Comment: @Sahil `installed_apps` has nothing to do with resolving Python modules. It only influences what apps Django loads on startup to discover template tags, models, etc.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can have `-` in your Python files

Comment: @Sahil Strictly speakding, that is also incorrect. Hyphens are allowed, but modules that include them require extra legwork to import.

Comment: Chubs, is `ams` on your Python path? Can you paste in your project structure?

Comment: Yes, please post your project code so other users can see where you are going wrong. Also, see this question about hyphens in module names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name

Comment: @Brian

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKDha.png is this what you are asking for??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution via a friend's assistance.
The import statement should look like this.

`from check import con`

Since they are in the same package an all modules inside a package are visible to each other, it is not necessary to include the app_name.
The editor may show warnings. In my case it highlighted the `check` as `unresolved import 'check'` but I was able to execute and it worked nonetheless.

Comment: **Thank you to everyone who tried to help, I appreciate it greatly.**

Answer (score 1):

please try to import like as below...

```
from project_name.app_name.file_name import import_variable_or_funtion
```

in your case...

```
from project_name.ams.conn import conn
```

Comment: It did not work for, this is my project tree sturcture...https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKDha.png

Maybe, you can guide me using this.

Comment: It still does not work, it actually shows an error in the editor. 
And a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Comment: have you added `ams` to your `installed_apps` ?

Comment: I have added ams to the installed apps of the settings.py and I still am getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

**You may need to take a look at the example below**

When you have the following directory and You are in the my_app directory, for example, you want to import `My_model`class from `models.py` to `admin.py`.

```
03/14/2020  10:04 PM    <DIR>          .
03/14/2020  10:04 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/14/2020  10:37 PM    <DIR>          .idea
03/12/2020  09:45 PM    <DIR>          env
03/14/2020  05:33 PM    <DIR>        > my_project
                                          __init__.py
                                          asgi.py
                                          settings.py
                                          urls.py
                                          wsgi.py
03/14/2020  10:06 PM    <DIR>         > my_app
                                          > migrations 
                                          __init__.py
                                          admin.py
                                          apps.py
                                          models.py
                                          tests.py
                                          urls.py
                                          views.py
03/12/2020  09:49 PM                   manage.py
03/14/2020  05:34 PM                   requirements.txt
03/14/2020  10:04 PM                   db.sqlite3
```

for example in this case that I created my_project with this format `django-admin startproject my_project .` you should import My_model class into the first line of `admin.py` in this format

```
from .models import my_model
```

Comment: I haven't added any models the models.py file. I just created two .py files and I have been trying to import a function from one file.

Check this...https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKDha.png