# Import a module from a subdirectory in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, fastapi

I have an api with a structure like this

```
my-api
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mymodule.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── docker-compose.yml
```

I'm trying to import mymodule.py into main.py per the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/) but when I do so get the error

```
File "./app/main.py", line 3
from my-api.app.api import allocate
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My import looks like this

```
from my-api.app.api import mymodule
```

and my Dockerfile CMD is

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "7833"]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `my-api` isn't a valid python module name. Modules cannot have a `-` in them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name

Comment: @match that was it, thanks!