# Python module import containing . and _

Tags: python, python-import

**Problem**:
I would like to import a module (name: Ex3.2_myModule) to a file (name: Ex3.2_Test.py). They are in the same directory. To do it I tried several options (i.e. screenshot) proposed in several other discussions on this topic (i.e. [Discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name) and [Discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)). Neither of them work.

Screenshot: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnFQg.png

**Question**: How can I import this module without changing the name of the module?

**Code**:

Ex3.2_Test.py

```
# 1
import Ex3.2_myModule as mm

#2
mm = __import__("Ex3.2_myModule")

#3
import importlib
mod = importlib.import_module("Ex3.2_myModule")


mm.helloWorld()
```

Ex3.2_myModule.py

```
def helloWorld():
    print("Hello, World")
```

**Solution**:
The solution proposed in [Discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) works after all. Thanks a lot to @a_guest for pointing it out!

Comment: Could you please provide the code in your post and not in the screenshot.

Comment: What does "import a module to a file" mean? If you mean to import a module *from* a file, you'll have to change the name of the file, or use the `importlib` module. The `import` statement treats the `.` as separating a package name from a contained module name, not as part of a single module name.

Comment: @tjallo: Thanks for your input!

Comment: @chepner: Might be a silly question, but isn't Ex3.2_Test.py a file where I import the module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: @a_guest Unfortunately not. Just tried it

Comment: @Pewepow Why not, what's the issue with that answer? It should work. What version of Python do you use?

Comment: @a_guest Now it worked. First time it didn't work because of complications with the path. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!
Is this post a duplicate now? I had looked at the post you linked before (in fact I linked it in my question) but didn't realize that it would solve my problem since the the topics are at first glance not identical.

Answer (score 2):

The situation is tricky, because dots mean subpackage structure to python. Never the less it is still kinda possible with imp:

```
import imp
mm = imp.load_source('mm', 'Ex3.2_myModule.py')

mm.helloWorld()
```

note: this is unorthodox and you are recommend to simply rename your modules instead.

Seeing as this is probably for an excersise, you should just rename your modules.

Comment: The [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) module is deprecated since Python 3.4.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Where should I post the error this gives me?

Comment: @Pewepow Is this for some kind of (school) exercise? (Because of the naming Ex3.2) If so please just change the name. If they give you a hard time about the name change, just explain to them that a decimal point in modules is for subpackages. Using them in your module name is inproper, and unpythonic, it's bad practice. They are literally teaching you bad practice, if they give you a hard time.

I know this isn't the answer to your question. But I think it is the answer to your problem! ;)

Comment: @tjallo You are right. It is bad practice and I will change the file name. However, I'd still like to know if there is a way to make it work with the current name. I might be a bit stubborn I have to admit :)

Answer (score 0):

The following stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602557/5386938 works on my machine

```py
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader 

spec = spec_from_loader("Ex3.2_myModule", SourceFileLoader("Ex3.2_myModule", ".\\Ex3.2_myModule.py"))
mm = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(mm)

mm.hello()
help(mm)
```

where the contents of Ex3.2_myModule.py is

```py
def hello():
    print('Hello, World!')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import imp
with open('Ex3.2_myModule.py', 'rb') as fp:
    mm = imp.load_module('models_admin', fp, 'models.admin.py', ('.py', 'rb', imp.PY_SOURCE) )
mm.helloWorld()
```