# Import package with specific character in Python

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import package in Python, but the is name include a '-'
from package-name import * says my - is invalid syntax
Can I fix it wihtout rename anything ? [Screenshot of the invalid syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AssW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

as is written here:
[Python module with a dash, or hyphen (-) in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583652/python-module-with-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-its-name)

You can do that using **import**(). For example:

```
foobar = __import__("foo-bar")
```