# Importing files from different folder, "__init__.py" does not work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I have seen many responses suggesting including an `__init__.py` file in the subdirectory of submodules in order to import them as python package, but I can't get it working for my project. My project directory structure looks like this:

```
helm-2022
├── model
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── model.ipynb
│   └── torchModelSummary.py
├── preprocess
│   └── preprocess.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── vis_utils.py
```

I want to import functions inside `vis_utils.py` in the notebook `model.ipynb` under model folder and `preprocess.py` under the preprocess folder. I have already added empty `__init__.py` under the utils folder. When I tried to import in `model.ipynb` using `from utils import vis_utils`, I still got `No module named 'utils'`. I have also tried to import by including the top directory `from helm-2020.utils import vis_utils`, but that gives me a syntax error because of the hyphen. I don't have permission to change the top directory name, so changing the hyphen is not an option. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The problem is the module you want to import is not in the same directory. it is in a subdirectory of the parent directory.

Comment: You can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Comment: You have a bit of a pickle. The only meaningful top-level package would be `helm-2022`, but importing a name with a dash isn't possible from an `import` statement (though you can use [`importlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659400/11082165)). If you really can't change the name of that directory, your best best would be to create a new directory inside of `helm-2022` (maybe `helm_2022`?) and make that directory the package root.

Comment: Also, `__init__.py` is only required to create packages in Python versions older than 3.3. See [PEP 420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) for more details.

Comment: Its that top directory name that's the problem. If you wanted to do relative imports, that top directory would be the package name, but as you've noted, that hyphen messes everything up. You could make each of the `model`, `preprocess` and `utils` into their own packages (add helm-2022 to the PYTHONPATH), but those are horrible names for packages and really should be together. I don't know a good name for this whole bunch of code together, but if you could create a directory with an awesome name, and move those subdirectories down, then you have something to work with.

Comment: Generally, once you get to the level where you are creating packages, you should make them build and installable with a setup.py. That discipline gives you a much better structure. Python kinda lets you get away with not installing your code, but that breaks down pretty quickly.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you so much. First time using setup.py. Thanks to these two documents: [writing setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html )and [installing](https://docs.python.org/3/install/ ). It works perfectly. I will keep using this approach.