# How to create documentation for Python project with filename having '-', for example 1-test.py

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to create a documentation for my python project using sphinx. When I do make html, i am getting errors arrivals.7`-`clean module:

> WARNING: invalid signature for automodule ('modules.1-test')
> WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting 'modules.1-test' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)

```
modules package
================

Submodules
----------

modules.1\ '-\'test module
-------------------------------

.. automodule:: modules.1-test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

arrivals.2\`-\`test module
-------------------------

.. automodule:: modules.2-test
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

The modules with py files not having '-' in their name are working. How to include '-' in file name for sphinx?

Comment: Avoid hyphens in module names. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7583652/407651.